# Check a dictionary contains an XElement attribute value

Tags: c#, xml

I have some xml in the following format:

```
<select>
  <option value="2" ID="451">Some other text</option>
  <option value="5" ID="005">Some other text</option>
  <option value="6" ID="454">Some other text</option>
  <option value="15" ID="015">Some other text</option>
  <option value="17" ID="47">Some other text</option>
</select>
```

I also have a dictionary that has a key value that I want to match to the ID of the relevant option in the xml above and return the dictionary value. I'm not sure how to acomplish this.

I was thinking of looping round the dictionary like so:

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> dictionaryEntry in dictionary)
        {
            if (dictionaryEntry.Key == "AttributeValue")
            {
               //do stuff here

            }
        }
```

But I'm unsure of how to compare?
Thanks

Comment: Because you have no code I'm not going to supply an answer, instead just general guidance. Use an xml parser to parse out the value you're using as a key for the dictionary. Get the dictionary value by doing `Dictionary[parsedOutOfXml]`. There are plenty of example of parsing xml in c#.

Comment: Where is the code that creates a Dictionary? A Dictionary is what? option ID,Value (i.e. ID being the key and Value being the Value?)

Comment: I already have a populated dictionary. The key value of one of the entries should match one of the ID attribute values of an option node above. If it does if want to return the value of the dictionary, if not do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        String xmlString = @"<select>
        <option value=""2"" ID=""451"">Some other text</option>
        <option value=""5"" ID=""005"">Some other text</option>
        <option value=""6"" ID=""454"">Some other text</option>
        <option value=""15"" ID=""015"">Some other text</option>
        <option value=""17"" ID=""47"">Some other text</option>
        </select>";

        Dictionary<string, string> theDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        theDict.Add("451", "Dict Val 1");
        theDict.Add("005", "Dict Val 2");
        theDict.Add("454", "Dict Val 3");
        theDict.Add("015", "Dict Val 4");
        theDict.Add("47", "Dict Val 5");

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
        {
            XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings();
            ws.Indent = true;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        if (reader.Name == "option")
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("ID: {0} \nValue: {1} \nDictValue: {2}", reader.GetAttribute("ID"), reader.GetAttribute("value"), theDict[reader.GetAttribute("ID")]));
                        }
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure what is in the dictionary that you mentioned but my guess was you 3 different values total, the "value" in the xml, the ID in the xml, and another value in the dictionary and the key in the dictionary is the ID in the xml. Assuming all of this is right then this will get you what you need from your xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary from your xml & then obtain the value based on the key.

Eg.

```
XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(XmlFileName);
var elements1 = (from items in doc1.Elements("select").Elements("option")
                             select items).ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("ID").Value, x => x.Attribute("value").Value);
```